# Fetching parameter from function defined in array in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects in a file.After importing this array in another file, when i map values , i get the error ISODate is not defined.

```
const details=[
    {
    "date": ISODate("2019-12-19T08:32:50.606Z"),
    "title":"title 1"
    },
    {
    "date": ISODate("2019-12-18T08:32:50.606Z"),
    "title":"title 2"
    },
    {
    "date": ISODate("2019-12-17T08:32:50.606Z"),
    "title":"title 3"
    }
    ]    
export default details
```

Desired Output:
I want to make a copy of array in the below format, so that i can map its values.

```
const details=[
        {
        "date": "2019-12-19",
        "title":"title 1"
        },
        {
        "date": "2019-12-18",
        "title":"title 2"
        },
        {
        "date": "2019-12-17",
        "title":"title 3"
        }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

"ISODate not defined"
At execution, the definition of `ISOdate` can't be found in none of the different [scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).
It means `ISOdate` is defined neither in the
block scope,
nor in function scope,
nor in module scope,
finally it seems not to be part of the global scope either: in the browser it is not part of the [standard built-in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects); out of the browser, it is not part of the [Node API](https://nodejs.org/api/).

So the question is, where is this function coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no ISODate at least natively on javascript, if you want to create a date variable and then print it I suggest you to use `"date":new Date("2019-12-19T08:32:50.606Z")` instead of ISODate, and then you can use that variable for formating the date, if you want your attribute "date" to be a string using a formatted date you can use:

```
const details=[
{
"date": new Date("2019-12-19T08:32:50.606Z").toLocaleDateString(),
"title":"title 1"
},
{
"date": new Date("2019-12-18T08:32:50.606Z").toLocaleDateString(),
"title":"title 2"
},
{
"date": new Date("2019-12-17T08:32:50.606Z").toLocaleDateString(),
"title":"title 3"
}
]    
export default details
console.log(details);
```

There are also other formatting methods for your date variable, feel free to look for them here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date